# Distributed transaction and Read Commited Snapshot

Tags: sql-server, distributed-transactions

Distributed transactions are not supported for snapshot isolation level in [SQL Server 2008R2](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179599%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). 
But what about read committed snapshot?

Comment: Cross posted [on dba.se](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48114/distributed-transaction-and-read-commited-snapshot#question)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes RCSI is supported for use with distributed transactions as documented in Books Online:

[Choosing Row Versioning-based Isolation Levels](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188277%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

[image: BOL extract]